# Method inside dispatcher called twice for an IAsyncAction.Completed handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous

#### Problem description

```
IAsyncAction myCheck = null;
myCheck = ThreadPool.RunAsync(
    (IAsyncAction source) =>
    {
        MyFirstTask();
    });

myCheck.Completed = new AsyncActionCompletedHandler(
    (IAsyncAction TaskCompletionSource, AsyncStatus status) =>
    {
        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () =>
            {
                MySecondTask();
            });
    });
```

In `MyFirstTask()`: I am getting list of files and I'll show them screen using `LongListMultiSelector`.

In `MySecondTask()`: I have defined one property `FileCount` which returns the file count that obtained from `MyFirstTask()`. Based on the property `FileCount` and files count, I'm showing "No items" text on screen if files count is zero (0) otherwise I'll display all items.

#### The problem

Before `MyFirstTask()` completes fully obtaining all files, `MySecondTask()` executes twice, so on first execution we get files count value zero (0). Due to this my UI gets updated with "No items" text... But immediately after 1-2 seconds, `MySecondTask()` again triggers the `FileCount` property with correct files count and I can see all files on the screen and that text "No items" will disappear.

Please note: This problem happening only when there are a large number of files, so for fewer files this problem is not there... (So, I strongly suspect this is due to sycnronization problems between threads.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: check if you're calling secondtask from anywhere else, also it just could be showing the default value in the beginning.

Comment: maybe the property `FileCount` is "binded" to the UI, so also called by data binding

Comment: Hi, I checked my removing "FileCount" which was binded to UI. Evenafter that the issue is there..

Comment: ThreadPool.RunAsync api is calling MyFirstTask() two times. How can I avoid it..?

Comment: The problem is resolved:-  I jus need to include if(myCheck.status == AsyncStatus.Completed) jus before calling MySecondTask()

Comment: But I need one more help, How I can cancel previous Async calls made. I used myCheck.Cancel()  but it did not improved performance when there're multiple calls to same Async function.